# How to bind to an element inside a ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, controltemplate

I've created two custom controls in wpf, `Control_A` and `Control_B`. Both of them define a `ColorProperty`. `Control_A`'s `ControlTemplate` consists of a `Control_B` instance,

```
<ControlTemplate 
   TargetType="{x:Type Control_A}">
   <Border 
      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

      <Control_B />

   </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

What I want is to bind `A.Color` (target) to `B.Color` (source). How can this be achieved in XAML?

Comment: I think you've got the data flow mixed up. It would be `ViewModel > View > Control_A > ControlTemplate > Control B`. `Control_B` is part of the composition of the template, so you couldn't bind to it directly / provide data dynamically without passing the data via `Control_A`.

Comment: Possibly you're right @Funk but I don't use MVVM.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with a `TwoWay` binding. This way has it's dissadvantages but it works,

```
<ControlTemplate 
   TargetType="{x:Type Control_A}">
   <Border 
      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

      <Control_B 
        Color="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Color, 
                Mode=TwoWay}"/>

   </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to give Control_B a Name and bind to its color.

```
Color="{Binding ElementName=Foo, Path=Color}"
```

Comment: But where would you write this inside the Control_A's `ControlTemplate`?

Comment: What you want to do with a color in a custom control is you decision. Maybe use it as the background of your border or maybe you need more elements where you can assign it. Or do you just want it to be assigned to your "self"?

Comment: I want the value of `Control_B.Color` to `Control_A.Color`. But the relationship between the two is that the one is the templated parent and the other the templated child.